# How can I see the output of printf inside gdb?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

This is what I tried,but seems not working:

```
(gdb) call printf("%d",6)
$8 = 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't see the result is because *stdout*(FILE*) has a output buffer. It won't output any to the screen until the buffer is full or '\n' is encountered.

so call printf like this:

```
(gdb) call (int)printf("%d\n", 6)
6
$6 = 2
```

BTW, The "$6 = 2" which is result value of *printf*.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it worked fine - `printf` returned 1, indicating that it successfully printed a single character to standard output.

Note that standard output isn't necessarily displayed in the same terminal that gdb is running in - it'll be displayed wherever the program you're debugging has its standard output (it's just as if the program itself had called `printf()` - the `call` command in gdb calls the function in the program's context).

Comment: How can I see the output of `printf`?

Comment: @assem: Look wherever `printf` would have gone if the program itself had called it.  You may really want the gdb command `print` rather than `call printf` - eg `print argc` would print the value of `argc` in the current context.